# Divisibility if linear combination elements do not divide

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I am trying to get a practice problem solved and I basically came to the following result.

What I need to prove is that some $x$ should not be divisible by $y$. The form of $y$ is $k(s.p_1 + t.p_2)$ and $k$ does not divide $x$, $p_1$ does not divide $x$, and $p_2$ does not divide $x$.

Can we conclude from here that $x$ is not divisible by $y$?

Comment: This is hard to follow.  Clearly, if $k$ isn't a divisor of $x$ then no multiple of $k$ could ever be a divisor of $x$.  Is that really what you intended to ask?

Comment: @lulu, yes, that is pretty much what I was trying to ask but how could we prove that if k is not a divisor of x, then no multiples of k would be a divisor of x?

Comment: Just think about it.  If $x=y\times N$ then $x=k\times ((sp_1+tp_2)\times N)$.

Comment: $y=kn\mid x\Rightarrow k\mid x\,$ contra hypothesis, by "divides" is transitive (cf. dupe).

Comment: I see, logically makes sense but since this is an academic exercise, I wanted to make sure that the answer fits to the academic standards.